# How to enable/disable button after the other button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 buttons that work like a process which is user need to click button 1 before button 2 is enabled to be click. To be able to click button 3, a user needs to click button 2 after then the button 3 is able to be a click, the same goes to button 4 which is all the button is enabled to click at the end when user click button 4. I manage to get button 1 and button 2 work but after user click button 2, button 3 is not able to click.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="280dp"
        android:onClick="goToAnotherActivity1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="@string/reconnaissance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:onClick="goToAnotherActivity2"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/scanning"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="goToAnotherActivity3"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/gaining_and_maintaining_access"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="goToAnotherActivity4"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/report"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the java code:

```
        package com.example.ProPentest;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


        public class phase_list extends AppCompatActivity implements 
        View.OnClickListener {

        Button button2, button3, button4, button5;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.phase_list);

            button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);

            button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public void goToAnotherActivity1(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, web_net.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void goToAnotherActivity2(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, web_net2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void goToAnotherActivity3(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, webnet3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void goToAnotherActivity4(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, report.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v==button2){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(phase_list.this, web_net.class);
                phase_list.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                button3.setEnabled(true);
                button4.setEnabled(false);
                button5.setEnabled(false);
            }

          if (v==button3) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(phase_list.this, web_net2.class);
              phase_list.this.startActivity(myIntent);
              button4.setEnabled(true);
              button5.setEnabled(false);
          }

            if (v==button4){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(phase_list.this, webnet3.class);
                phase_list.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                button5.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be like a process which user need to click the button step by step to enable the next button.

Comment: first enable/disable buttons then use startActivity()

Comment: you forgot to declare setOnclickListerner of  your other buttons button3.setOnClickListener(this); button4 and button5.

Comment: btw your code is redundant. executing the onclick method and onclicklistener has the same operation intent. Probably you should only use one of the two either onClick method call or onClicklistener

Comment: thank you all for the help ...i will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add     **setOnClickListener(this);** for button3,4 and 5 after assigning the ids to the variables.

**Like:-**`

```
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
button3.setOnClickListener(this);
button4.setOnClickListener(this);
button5.setOnClickListener(this);`
```

Suggestion:- for better coding use switch statements inside onClick(View v) method for batter handling the particular button click.

Answer (score 0):

you defined both `android:onClick` and `setOnClickListener` to do different task simultaneously.I am not sure you can do it. 
I think you should manage it in a listener.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove this section

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==button2){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(phase_list.this, web_net.class);
        phase_list.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        button3.setEnabled(true);
        button4.setEnabled(false);
        button5.setEnabled(false);
    }

  if (v==button3) {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(phase_list.this, web_net2.class);
      phase_list.this.startActivity(myIntent);
      button4.setEnabled(true);
      button5.setEnabled(false);
  }

    if (v==button4){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(phase_list.this, webnet3.class);
        phase_list.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        button5.setEnabled(true);}
}
```

> Update this section

```
 public void goToAnotherActivity1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, web_net.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void goToAnotherActivity2(View view) {
        button3.setEnabled(true);
        button4.setEnabled(false);
        button5.setEnabled(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, web_net2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void goToAnotherActivity3(View view) {
        button4.setEnabled(true);
        button5.setEnabled(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, webnet3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void goToAnotherActivity4(View view) {
        button5.setEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, report.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

> Also i have notices that you just have implemented click listener programmatically only on button 2 in onCreate method so only call will return to onClick() overridden method for button 2

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:

              // you can put your code hear. As per button SetEnabled and Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button 3 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button 4 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button 5 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** **Remove in your xml file** Button property `android:onClick` because in your code you Override the `onClick` method and `goToAnotherActivity1/2/3/4`  both are same thing.

I hope it'll help you...!